# Bring forward an object by clicking a button in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, if-statement, button, powerpoint

I have a PPT  presentation with some slides. In each slide I have some superposed images and some buttons (see example image).
[image]
I would like to "bring to front" an image when the corresponding button is clicked.
I have been triying with animations, but unfortunately there is no animation to run this action.
After some 'investigation' I think that the only way to achieve that is by a macro.

I have absolutely no experience in VBA programming, but after some search I found out the way to 'bring to front' an image of the active slide by doing:

```
Sub Bring_front()
Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
sld.Shapes("NUCLEI").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub`
```

Then I insert an action (to execute the macro) to the correspoding button and everything works fine!

The problem is that in my real presentation I have many images and buttons (like 10 for slide)... and I would like to create a macro with if/else statements in order to run an statement if a button is clicked.
I have also been searching how to do that but I have not been able to get it.

Is it possible to do something like that?:

```
Sub Bring_front()

Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

 if Greenbutton is clicked Then
      sld.Shapes("GREEN_IMAGE").ZOrder msoBringToFront
 elseif Redbutton is clicked Then
      sld.Shapes("RED_IMAGE").ZOrder msoBringToFront
 elseif Bluebutton is clicked Then
      sld.Shapes("BLUE_IMAGE").ZOrder msoBringToFront
 end


End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this, please?

Thank you in advance!

Maria

Comment: dsdsActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("animateMe").ZOrder msoBringToFront

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple:

Add a new module in the VBA editor and paste this into it:

```
Sub MoveToTop(oSh As Shape)
    Call oSh.ZOrder(msoBringToFront)
End Sub
```

Then assign this MoveToTop macro as an action setting on each of the shapes you want to be able to adjust.

That's it.

Well, almost. If you're on a Mac and find that this doesn't work, it's because some things in the Mac version of PPT are broken. In that case, try this, which should work ok in Windows versions of PPT also:

```
Sub MoveToTop(oSh as Shape)

   Dim oSl as Slide
   Dim oShTemp as Shape

   ' oSh.Parent returns a valid reference to the shape's host slide:  
   Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(oSh.Parent.SlideIndex)

   ' and oSh.Name works:
   MsgBox oSh.Name

   ' So we use those two bits to get a reference 
   ' to the clicked shape like so
   Set oShTemp = oSl.Shapes(oSh.Name)

   Call oShTemp.ZOrder(msoBringToFront)

End Sub
```